# Print Screen key doesn't work if a drop-down menu is active

Tags: keyboard, screenshot

On 11.10, I don't get a screengrab when pressing the Print Screen button on my keyboard if I have activated a drop down menu.  For example, in nautilus, I can click the File menu and press the print screen button, nothing happens.  Deactivating the drop down menu and all other things being equal, it works.  Is that normal?  Often when using this thing I'm actually needing to show some of those menu options.

Currently I use the workaround to grab after a delay of a few seconds, but I'm used to the print screen button working no matter what's in focus and would prefer it that way.

Comment: I can confirm this occurs under both Unity and GNOME Shell sessions. BTW, this has already been reported as [bug 29894](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-utils/+bug/29894) and has been around since early 2006.

Comment: Another side note: you can still use the Print Screen key when you have menus open from the top panel in GNOME Shell. Not sure why that's different, but it seems to at least work there.

Comment: As this question is highly ranked on search engines, I propose this question gets reopened so we can list all possible workarounds, I already submitted an edit to fit this purpose. Maybe @Jorge-Castro can take a look?

Comment: Meanwhile, if you are reading this because got this result on google, yahoo, bing, etc. or even askubuntu's own search (first and top result) and are in desperate need of a workaround, you can read the detailed instructions I wrote: http://askubuntu.com/a/488194/173578

Comment: use `scrot -d 5` see here: http://askubuntu.com/a/114722/46437

Comment: still a bug....

Answer (score -1):

and what about [shutter](http://shutter-project.org/) it will work without a problem, but you need to rebind the print key to shutter

Rebinding the print key:
- open compiz
- go to gnome compatibility
[image]

- switch to commands tap and in the Screenshot command line Write `shutter -f -d 3`
this will take a screen-shot after 3 seconds and you can take a screen-shot for you menus or simple ignore the 3 seconds delay and it will also work by this command `shutter -f`
[image]

 Now you can take a screen-shot to any menu you want, for more options see [this](http://shutter-project.org/faq-help/man-page/).

Comment: +1 But can you add steps on how to rebind print key to shutter in your answer

Comment: I think he means to create a custom shortcut on keyboard options to run shutter in the command line, as from withing shutter I found no options for that.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/609487/replace-gnome-screenshot-save-option-with-shutter-edit-screen-or-atleast-shutter