# PrintScreen doesn't work when I'm in a context menu

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I usually take screenshots printscreen which calls into gnome-screenshots. Today I noticed that it doesn't work when the context menu is open. The simplest case is when I right click on desktop and press printscreen nothing happens. Is this some sort of bug? Any knows how  to fix this?

Comment: It's end of 2023 now. This is still an issue!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's a known problem i guess , it happens in KDE as well.

But if you want screenshots when menu is running , you can switch to command line tools , or set a timeout.

Command line , e.g delay for 5 seconds :  `scrot -cd 5`

For ksnapshot , you can delay for seconds , and then take a shot.

Comment: Setting timeouts with [gnome screenshot](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/) will still not capture the context menu.

Comment: This still works fine in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Works in XUbuntu 22.04 - but feels weird having to use this trick

Answer (score 9):

It's not exactly a bug, it's just that the gnome screenshot doesn't have this feature.

Other tools, like [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/), can do it.

[image]

Comment: xfscreenshot is also affected by this bug.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a bug, it'a feature... We have become used to this logic with Microsoft and it's more and more present in Linux too...

Comment: @Camion: hahaha I listen to this exact sentence a lot in my office. I turned over to make sure I read it and did not just hear it over once again.

Comment: This should be the selected answer, since the selected answer's solution does not work with [gnome screeshot](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/), as stated here.

Comment: Shutter also does not do it! Just checked. If it stops working for gnome screenshot it is also not working for Shutter.

Comment: Shutter doesn't work for me on Xubuntu 22.04