# Can't run gnome-screenshot while right click menu is open in eclipse

Tags: gnome, i3-wm, gnome-screenshot

I have my print-screen button set to run 'gnome-screenshot' and it normally works fine but if I right click on a project in eclipse the program seems to be blocked from running until the right-click menu is off the screen.

I should also note that I'm running i3-wm and I'm also blocked from using 'win+d' to open another program.

It opens no problem when I try the same thing in Firefox.

Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: I hope that maybe someone has an answer for this, as I too have noticed this that if you right click on the desktop and a menu is open it will not take a screenshot.  Also, I use Synergy between hosts, and if a menu like that is open, I cannot move the mouse to the next screen until the menu is closed.

Comment: firefox would be one of the rare exceptions, for the most part if a context menu is open you can't take a screenshot from a key press. Nothing new or unexpected.

Comment: I guess it is a known issue.  I saw a helpful command in the answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/114718/231142 that might work.

Comment: @Terrance the delay worked should I close my question?

Comment: That's up to you.  Maybe we can close it with a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @Terrance good idea I have flagged the question