# Kubuntu 18.04 - Right click, open terminal here

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu

Is there a simple way to add a shortcut to the right-click contextual menu so that I can open a terminal in the **current directory** that I'm in? The solutions I've seen so far are way too convoluted for such a trivial task. I'm asking in the hope that there is a simple solution to this, it's also likely the answer is right in front of me and I'm over complicating this.

I was going to provide a screenshot but unable to take one whilst the right-click contextual menu is open!! Is this a bug?

Comment: Have you tried `Shift+F4`? No need for a right-click and then choosing from a contextual menu.

Comment: Your screenshot issue is a separate question and should be asked separately but Spectacle, Kubuntu's screenshot tool, and most other screenshot tools have a *delay* option.

Comment: And what is "The solutions I've seen so far are way too convoluted" all about? Which solutions are you thinking of?

Comment: Thank you DK Bose. Both the Shift+F4 and delay option you mentioned are great solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Dolphin has "Open Terminal Here" option under Actions in the context menu. If it's not there, you can turn it on by going into Settings > Configure Dolphin and then turning it on in Services. You can also find other useful actions here.

You can hit Super+Print screen to capture the active window with Spectacle.

Answer (score 0):

[Right click > Actions > Open Terminal Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Trq.png)

If that option isn't there open up Dolphin and go into Control > Configure Dolphin > Services and make sure 'Open Terminal Here' is checked.

The screenshot solution I used was the command line utility scrot. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114718/printscreen-doesnt-work-when-im-in-a-context-menu).