# How can I get Unity to show the menu icons in Inkscape?

Tags: 12.04, unity, icons, menu, inkscape

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and I have enabled icons in menus. Everything works fine except Inkscape that shows a lot of "missing" icons. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which missing icons? can you add a screenshot?

Comment: It is, but just [set a 2-3 second delay](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72208/print-screen-key-doesnt-work-if-a-drop-down-menu-is-active) and do it.

Comment: I got it but I don't have enough "reputation" to post it.

Comment: Upload it somewhere and post a link, I'll add it for you.

Comment: now you have some reputation :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [long running bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/inkscape/+bug/775702) for which there are workarounds (see comments #29 and #30 in the bug).

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for!