# Taking screenshots in Lubuntu (11.10)

Tags: 11.10, lubuntu, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print Screen key doesn't work if a drop-down menu is active](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72208/print-screen-key-doesnt-work-if-a-drop-down-menu-is-active)

As you know, by pushing <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> button on the keyboard, a screen-shot of desktop will be saved on your home folder, but why it doesn't work when I open a menu?

For example, when I open LXDE menu and then pressing PrintScreen, nothing happen. Neither when menus such as File, Edit, View and etc. are open.

Comment: http://wiki.lxde.org/en/How_to_take_screenshots

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The quick way to take a screenshot on Lubuntu is simply hitting the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> button. It saves your file to your home folder.

***The software mentioned below, Kgrab, and Ksnapshot, bothe were installed from the Lubuntu Software Center.  Meanwhile, mtPaint was available by default under the Graphics menu.***

[image]

However, certain actions can't be captured using the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> button. Sometimes a time delay is required in order to begin a specific function. I use **Kgrab**

[image]
[image]
[image]

or **Ksnapshot**

[image]

As you can see both have the options to choose full screen, wndows, etc.., and both have time delay.

You can use mtPaint. It comes default on Lubuntu. In the menu, there's a timedelayed screenshot option.  Not as easy as the above, but it will do the job.

Comment: i want to take screenshots whenever i push PrintScreen. can i set KGrab (or Ksnapshot) the default program in lubuntu for that??

Comment: I wouldn't rush to install anything starting with **K** because you're on Lubuntu. **K** often indicates **KDE** which means you'll be bringing in a whole bunch of dependencies. My suggestion is to use the default screenshot software you already have. You haven't mentioned its name.

Comment: @vasa1 I agree, but these were available on the Lubuntu Software Center.  You can use mtPaint. It comes default on Lubuntu. In the menu, there's a timedelayed screenshot option.

Comment: @vasa1 I didnt install anything extra, its the default program which i think is "scrot".

Comment: Then try `man scrot` and look carefully for an option that allows you to specify a time delay. If it does exist, you'll have to resort to using the terminal if you selectively want `scrot` to use a time delay. Otherwise, try what Mitch has suggested: `mtPaint`.

Comment: the only way for delay is using terminal, but it solve my problem :) thank u vasa1, and you Mitch for your help

Answer (score 8):

Use Shutter, it's something like Snipping tool on Win7.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install shutter
```

As you open it you have New - Selection / Desktop / Active window...

Comment: Where do I find "New - Selection / Desktop ... "?

Comment: As of October of 2021, package 'shutter' has no installation candidate on Lubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 4):

This is because pressing PrintScreen usually makes the menu go away. You can work around this by setting a delay before you take the screenshot. For instance, if you have `imagemagick` installed you can do the following on a terminal:

```
sleep 10; import -window root <filename>.png
```