# Replace gnome-screenshot save option with shutter edit screen or atleast shutter main screen in ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: shutter, print-screen

Normally when i press print screen button in the keyboard, I get gnome-screenshot windows as this ..

[image]

Is there a way to replace this windows with shutter edit screen or at least shutter main screen, When i press printscreen button ?

I have tried creating custom shortcut in All Settings ⇒ Keyboard ⇒ custom shortcut and added `shutter -f` ..

[How to make Shutter as the default screenshot tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252717/how-to-make-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool)

Instead of opening any windows with more edit options it just save the image.. Then i have to find the image and open with shutter...

Most of the switches i have checked in the above link with shutter.. 
and tried shutter help /google..

Yet could not get what i want.. I want to get shutter edit screen or at least shutter main screen with the image grabbed when i press printscreen.. Is this possible? What im missing here ? Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried it my self.... Here are the steps..

Disable gnome printscreen shotcuts .. (`All Settings--->Keyboard---->Screenshots`)

[image]

Next create shortcuts as preferred (`All Settings--->Keyboard---->Custom shortcuts` )

```
Shutter -f
```

[image]

And assign  printscreen key. ( See more for how to assign a custom key ) [How to add keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331626/how-to-add-keyboard-shortcuts)

And next shortcut for shutter -a

[image]

And assign alt key and printscreen ( See more for how to assign a custom key ) [How to add keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331626/how-to-add-keyboard-shortcuts)

Then open shutter and go to menu (`Edit--->preference--->main`)
Select Do not save file automatically

[image]

**+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++**

**At this point you have achieve main screen by pressing printscreen button or Alt + printscreen button..** 
**+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++**

To open **edit windows, instead of main screen**, when ressing printscreen button or Alt + printscreen button, go to Actions in preference and select open with Built-in Editor

[image]

And make sure other settings remain as below in behavior section,

[image]

Done!!

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I've implemented it for me too. However, disabling the standard shortcuts is not intuitive. I've found that it works if you are using Alt+noting and wait - probably a workaround. Also the Alt+Print combination doesn't work, chose Shift+Print.