# Lubuntu/Xlde > is there a way to change scrot printscreen default saving option to shutter?

Tags: lubuntu, 15.04, shutter, print-screen, scrot-command

Previously i was using ubuntu and had to switch due to pc performance issue.. Is there a way to 
Previously i got gnome-print-screen option replaced by shutter edit option from below thread for ubuntu.. Looking for the same for Lubuntu..

[Replace gnome-screenshot save option with shutter edit screen or atleast shutter main screen in ubuntu 14.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609487/replace-gnome-screenshot-save-option-with-shutter-edit-screen-or-atleast-shutter)

Not sure how to do the same in Lubuntu 15.04. ? Is this thing prossible or I have to live with default option of **scrot** printscreen that images are silently saved in a directory, when i press printscreen, without any popup or screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to change keyboard shortcuts in Lubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard#Create_New_Keyboard_shortcuts
Open `lubuntu-rc.xml` in your favorite editor.. (Mine its vim, it could be leafpad/vi/nano )

```
  `sudo vim ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`
```

then find the following code..

```
<keybind key="Print">
           <action name="Execute">
           <command>lxsession-default screenshot</command> 
           </action>
 </keybind>
```

Comment out  `<command>lxsession-default screenshot</command>` and add `<command>shutter -f</command>` .. (or just you can replace, instead of commenting, but I prefer doing so)

```
<keybind key="Print">
       <action name="Execute">
       <!-- <command>lxsession-default screenshot</command> -->
       <command>shutter -f</command>
       </action>
 </keybind>
```

And also you can replace ( Alt + Print ) option by changing to this shutter -a in the following manner..

```
<keybind key="A-Print">
      <action name="Execute">
        <!--<command>lxsession-default screenshot window</command> -->
        <command>shutter -a</command>
      </action>
 </keybind>
```

Then reload openbox

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

Rest are same as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609487/replace-gnome-screenshot-save-option-with-shutter-edit-screen-or-atleast-shutter)
Then open shutter and go to menu (`Edit--->preference--->main`)
Select Do not save file automatically

[image]

**+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++**

**At this point you have achieve main screen by pressing printscreen button or Alt + printscreen button..** 
**+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++**

To open **edit windows, instead of main screen**, when ressing printscreen button or Alt + printscreen button, go to Actions in preference and select open with Built-in Editor

[image]

And make sure other settings remain as below in behavior section,

[image]

Done!!

Comment: can you comment on why i wouldn't just reconfigure the default lxsession behavior?