# Screenshot application which can capture everything, including menus

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu ships with some `gnome-screenshot`, which can take screenshots of both the entire screen and screen parts. Unfortunately, it doesn't work if some menu is activated, i.e. I can't take a screenshot of a dropdown menu. In other cases the menu is closed when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>.

This is an imperfection which Greenshot does not have.

Is there a normal screenshot application in Ubuntu which can capture everything, including menus?

Comment: Just pressing print screen by itself should do the trick....

Comment: It will shot entire screen

Comment: And then you just crop it in GIMP

Comment: @AndroidDev very pure automation

Comment: greenshot is only for Windows. I'm not sure there's any Linux equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/). It works with any flavor of Ubuntu.

You can install it with apt or apt-get in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install shutter
```

If you prefer, 
you can set it as default PrtScr shortcut app in [Ubuntu/Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252717/how-to-make-shutter-as-the-default-screenshot-tool) and in [Lubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621073/lubuntu-xlde-is-there-a-way-to-change-scrot-printscreen-default-saving-option)

To make capturing a windows dropdown menu easier give yourself 3 seconds of additional time to show the windows dropdown menu after selecting the window that gets a screenshot of it taken. Select *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> in left pane select *Main* -> in the number picker after where it says *Capture after a delay of* select **3** seconds.

Comment: Shutter uses delay, which is not comfortable. Are there any programs which can just shot what I want, without any tricks?

Comment: Shutter doesn't use any delay by default. By default the delay in Shutter is 0 seconds if you don't change it in the number picker. I prefer to use a delay because it gives me extra time to move the mouse.

Comment: Without delay it can't shot menu (selected region)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been quite a long time, but in case you didn't solve it, I had the same problem and I found the solution in the pre-installed software in Ubuntu, notably the "Screenshot" app (it should be under "Activities", or "Accessories").

This will let you print a desired region of the screen. You'll need to see or set the triggering actions under the "Keyboard" system section, "Shortcut" tab (I had the <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>PrnScreen</kbd> on default). There are also a number of other options.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install a GUI program, you can just use `scrot` (`sudo apt install scrot`). To make a screenshot of the whole screen after five seconds (`-d 5`) and save it to `~/screenshot.png` execute in a terminal:

```
scrot -d 5 ~/screenshot.png
```

To make the screenshot of the (to that time) active window (`-u`) including its border (`-b`) after five seconds and save it to `~/screenshot.png` execute:

```
scrot -u -b -d 5 ~/screenshot.png
```

Read more on [scrot's manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/scrot.1.html).

Comment: It is expected, that user first runs `scrot` with delay, then call menu within this delay. People just didn't work with `greenshot` and think these tricks are unavoidable.

Comment: @Dims Setting the delay is not a “trick”, but rather a feature –image a situation where you need keystrokes at the time of the screenshot! However if you can't resign from using your favorite windows program, just [use it with wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30122).

Comment: @Dim The advantage of linux OSes is clearly that you can set things like you want them to be – if you want to have a key on your keyboard that does e.g. `scrot -u -b ~/screenshot.png`, just [configure it that way](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html)!

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late for this but I thought may be it will help another person who will face this kind of problem so for this purpose use built-in app named "**SCREENSHOT**".
I'm using UBUNTU BUDGIE 18.04 LTS 64-bit, and this application will also be present in UBUNTU 18.04.
Hope so it will help you.