# Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome default directory for gnome-screenshot?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, files, screenshot, dconf

How can I change default screenshots folder?

I tried to use `dconf-editor`:

> org -> gnome -> gnome-screenshot

At `auto-save-directory` I typed the desired directory in the following format:

```
file:///home/user/Desktop/
```

I tried all format actually, but couldn't find.

Is there anybody who knows how can I change my default directory?

Comment: Just to be sure, did you forget to replace **user** in the path by your username?

Comment: I think you must (also) set the dconf key `last-save-directory` to the same path. Gnome-screenshot is a bit buggy in that regard for years... See https://askubuntu.com/a/114458/367990

Comment: Why not to use Shutter? It's practical and highly customizable... See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/947141/screenshot-application-which-can-capture-everything-including-menus