# Shortcut to reneable shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gimp, print-screen

Ubuntu 16.04 all up to date.

I used PrtScr to capture a screen then went to Gimp and did some editing. During which, I was using Gimp's shortcuts,
click-shift for point to point line then also hold down Ctrl for Ortho-line. All went well until I exited Gimp and now PrtScr does not work.

But, my guess is that one of the Gimp key-combos I used has also shut off PrtScr. Can someone please tell me what to try to turn it back on again.

I did some searching and mostly the stuff I found talked about the shortcut keys and offered complex fixes.

Thanks.

Comment: What has Gimp got to do with this? If a key disabled PrtSc, Gimp didn't see it. Desktop managers often use Alt-* keys and there are some Gimp shortcuts that also use Alt (and aren't usable in Gimp). Also stating your desktop manager would help. Then we would know what utility is hidden behind `PrtSc` and we could suggest ways to restart it.

Comment: @xenoid I mentioned Gimp as immediately on leaving it PrtScr no longer worked. The logic of that is perhaps a bug in the system was seeing a Gimp key combo as something to turn off the PrtScr key. Desktop manager is whatever comes with Ubuntu 16.04. Bog stock standard Ubuntu. If I had changed it I **would** have mentioned it. :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/609487/replace-gnome-screenshot-save-option-with-shutter-edit-screen-or-atleast-shutter tells you how to access the shortcut keys, etc..