# Print screen bug is getting worse [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, printing

You might have heard of the [15 year old bug in Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/29894) that has never been fixed ([mentioned on this forum a decade ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72208/print-screen-key-doesnt-work-if-a-drop-down-menu-is-active)). Essentially you can't printscreen while a menu is active.

Today, I was working **with two monitors**, vscode in one and the browser on the other. I right clicked on the vscode text editor to open the [context menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_menu). While opened, I tried taking a rectangular screenshot using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> and click-and-dragged on the vscode app to select the screenshot region. Then BAM.

Not only it didn't work, but the whole UI became buggy. I couldn't click anything anymore, I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tabing</kbd> sometimes and I was eventually able to click on the browser, but the rest is still unresponsive (side and top menus aren't clickable, vscode isn't clickable...)

I feel this bug is just getting worse with time, and it's kind of mindblowing it has never been fixed.

**Is there any known workaround for this?**

Comment: In 20.04 I use a combination of `Screenshot tool` and `Shutter` which work perfectly well.

Comment: `Shutter` is great at freezing my computer if you have screen scaling on (e.g. 125%). Crashes my system quite regularly too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the context menu blocks the keyboard events and this is not a bug with Ubuntu, it happens with other distributions too and other desktop environments. Yes, I agree it's annoying but the work around is to use a timed screen capture utility, search for "screenshot" in the applications menu and set "**Grab after a delay of**" to the amount of seconds you want it to wait before taking the screenshot and click "Take Screenshot".

[image]